# Why isn't scapy capturing VLAN tag information?

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, scapy

I've been using my raspberry pi as a sniffer, and have observed some interesting differences between tcpdump and scapy.  I am seeing the following:

**Traffic Generator Machine, Linux Box with scapy:**

```
sendp(Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',src="AA:00:00:00:00:00")/Dot1Q(vlan=10)/IP()/ICMP())
```

**Raspberry Pi, ala 'tcpdump':**

```
00:25:10.156830 aa:00:00:00:00:00 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100),length 60: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, localhost > localhost: ICMP echo request, id 0, seq 0, length 8
```

**Rasperry Pi, via 'scapy':**

```
>>> pkt[0].show()
###[ Ethernet ]###   
    dst= ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff   
    src= aa:00:00:00:00:00   
    type= 0x800
###[ IP ]###
       version= 4L
       ihl= 5L
       tos= 0x0
       len=28
       id= 1
       flags= 
       frag= 0L
       ttl= 64
       proto= icmp
       chksum= 0x7cde
       src= 127.0.0.1
       dst= 127.0.0.1
       \options\
###[ ICMP ]###
          type= echo-request
          code= 0
          chksum= 0xf7ff
          id= 0x0
          seq= 0x0
###[ Padding ]###
              load= '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' None
```

Even when I try:

```
>>> Dot1Q in pkt[0]
False
```

**Does anyone know why scapy is unable to capture (parse?) the vlan frame, but tcpdump sees it fine ?**

(PS I also sniffed with scapy, and exported a pcap file, and then read the pcap file with tcpdump... the vlan tags are gone... disappeared... )

=======================

For those interested, my workaround for now is to use tcpdump to capture to a pcap file, and then use rdpcap() in scapy to load that data, so I can use scapy's powerful parsing features to explore the capture- this introduces a layer of caching, and a nasty system call into my program, but gets me reliable vlan information...

=======================

Based on RyPeck's answer and GuyHarris's advice, I now have a much better workaround:

a) Using http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/

```
import pcap
conf.use_pcap=True
```

b) Using pcappy - which is can be installed with: `pip install pcappy`

```
import pcappy as pcap
conf.use_pcap=True
```

Now scapy shows the same vlan information as tcpdump, with all it's great parsing features intact!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: support was added in [GH2091](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/2091) and is now available in Scapy 2.4.3+, on Python 3 only**

This was recently discussed in the Scapy mailing list [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.scapy.general/4929/focus=4938).

> As I said and pointed out, earlier, the vlan layer is stripped by the
>   kernel before scapy or tcpdump get it. But tcpdump now has support to
>   add it back. Hence you can create a ticket for scapy to support this
>   enhancement too. - Philippe Biondi (Scapy Inventor)

This explains why the VLAN Layer is disappearing. Nothing to do at this time except get in on a potential feature request/ticket. Feel free to create one over at the [Scapy BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/wiki/Home).

@[GuyHarris offered a different potential solution](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.scapy.general/4929/focus=4941), that having aforementioned feature in tcpdump will add the support for Scapy, this would apply for you if your Scapy installation is using libpcap to capture packets.

Comment: Thanks RyPeck - After playing around with what GuyHarris suggested, I managed to get the workaround to work!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do what you said but it didn't work. 'conf.L2listen 'still used 'PF_PACKETS' instead of libpcap. I started looking into the code and found that 'conf.use_pcap' is processed only in the 'pcapdnet' module. That means that if you don't import it, 'conf.use_pcap' is discarded and 'conf.L2listen' remains 'PF_PACKETS' instead of changing to 'L2pcapListenSocket' (which is the socket that binds to libpcap).

the solution is simple:

```
conf.use_pcap = True
import scapy.arch.pcapdnet
```

make sure that the you import the module AFTER you change the configuration, otherwise it won't work.
you can check that it worked if you look at:

```
conf.L2listen
```

and the value is:

```
 <L2pcapListenSocket: read packets at layer 2 using libpcap>
```

it didn't work if the value is:

```
<L2ListenSocket: read packets at layer 2 using Linux PF_PACKET sockets>
```